# How i can use hasClass on "class1 class2" without point as prefix an a comma between classes only as a string

Tags: jquery

normaly its easy to check if a element as minimum two defined classes

```
<div id="MYELEMENT" class="testA testC testD testF"></div>

if ($('#MYELEMENT').hasClass('.testC, .testD')){ alert('fine'); }
```

Now i have the situation, that i have only a string with a dynmicaly number of classes

```
var checkthis= "testA";
or
var checkthis= "testA testB";
or
var checkthis= "testD testF testB";
etc.
```

How can i work with this string in the easiest way to chcek if this classes are inside the "MYELEMENT"?

Comment: `.hasClass(checkthis.replace(" ", ","))` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m ok, but also the comma missed, or not? I think at the end of your idear i have ".testA, testB" or ".testD, .testF, .testB"

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking - `var checkthis` can only contain one value at a time.  Your variable value has spaces. Your `hasClass` check uses commas so convert spaces to commas.. However I don't believe ".testC,.testD" is valid for .hasClass which should take a class name, not a selector - it certainly shouldn't be with "." - so your original should have been `if ($("#id").hasClass("testC") || $("#id").hasClass("testD"))` *or* it should have been `if ($("#id").is(".testC,.testD")`

Comment: @freedomn-m yes i think it must be if ($("#id").is(".testC,.testD")  at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need that at least one of the classes to be true, you can use .is():

```
var strgClass = "testA testC";
var strgClassReplace = `.${strgClass.replace(/ /g, ",.")}`;

if($("#MYELEMENT").is(strgClassReplace)) {
  console.log("it only needs one class to become true");
}
```

And if you need it all be true, you can use the .filter() :

```
var strgClass = "testA testC";
var strgClassReplace = `.${strgClass.replace(/ /g, ".")}`;

if($("#MYELEMENT").filter(strgClassReplace).length) {
  console.log("all classes must be in the element to be true");
}
```

Hope this helps ;D